# How to overwrite or clear data in a Drive Table in Google App Maker

Tags: google-app-maker

I have loaded data from a Google Sheet into an App Maker datasource. Now I have made a change to the original sheet and want to import the new data and overwrite the old or alternatively just clear the existing data and import the new data from the sheet. I don't see a way to do either in [the docs](https://developers.google.com/appmaker/models/import-export#import_your_data_from_a_google_spreadsheet).

Comment: If I understand correctly, you need to manually synchronize data from a spreadsheet into a Google Drive Model database. I believe you need to build a server script using the [Spreadsheet service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/). I will investigate and try to see if there is another way.

Comment: I just need to delete or overwrite the data that's already there. It must be a very common requirement for testing so I wouldn't expect to write custom code to do it.

Comment: I'm happy to announce that App Maker supports [whole DB import/export with delete all option](https://developers.google.com/appmaker/release-notes#import_and_export_relations) now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I use the following command to clear a drivetable when needed:

```js
app.datasources.DatasourceName.unload();
```

**Edit:**

This will clear the table on the client. To delete all Records in a drive table use the following **server script**:

```js
var records = app.models.ModelName.newQuery().run();
app.deleteRecords(records);
```

Comment: I tried the second command, but it's not working for me. My datasource is named `Devices` and I'm running `var records = app.models.Devices.newQuery().run(); app.deleteRecords(records);` on button press.

Comment: @IanH are you running the second command form a server side script?

Comment: No, it was in the same page - but I reloaded the app and it worked! I may have made a typo or something.